# What is the best approache to share a UnitOfWork between two Repositories using Unity?

Tags: repository, inversion-of-control, unity-container, unit-of-work, object-lifetime

I want to use Unity as an IoC besides the UnitOfWork and Repository patterns. I read various related articles and questions but none of them satisfied me completely.
I have a problem with all approaches. An example would explain better my problem:

We want to work with two repositories at two separate classes (maybe the business services) but the overall works are in a unit.

Start point is the LocalService1.Method1 method.

```
public class LocalService1
{
    public void Method1(int id)
    {
        var repository1 = Container.Current.Resolve<IRepository1>(); // Injects the IUnitOfWork for the repository.
        var entity1 = repository1.GetEntity1(id);
        var service2 = Container.Current.Resolve<LocalService2>(); // Maybe it’s better not to use IoC for business logic. This is not my issue.
        service2.Method2(entity1)
    }
}
...
public class LocalService2
{
    public void Method2(Entity1 entity1)
    {
        var repository2 = Container.Current.Resolve<IRepository2>(); // Injects the IUnitOfWork for the repository.
        var count = repository2.GetEntity2sCount(entity1.Id);
        // Do some works with count and entity1
    }
}
```

The main question is that “How can I share the UnitOfWork (here can be ObjectContext) between the IRepository1 and IRepsitory2 while calling the LocalService1.Method1?”.
More important thing is that “I want to be sure about UnitOfWork disposal”.

I guess the answers would focus on these issues:

- IoC configuration
- Life Time configuration
- Disposal time (How and when?)

**If you recommend using “HttpContext” please consider about non-web environments.**

I know my question is almost about the “Life time management” but I’m looking for an exhaustive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Don't use Unity as a ServiceLocator. This is [considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Use [constructor injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) instead.

Unity's LifetimeManagers don't clean up after themselves. This feature is on the [wish list for Unity vNext](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general/suggestions/1672391-unity-lifetimes-teardown-should-dispose-objects-c).

If you want your objects to be disposed you should [create your own LifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660885%28PandP.20%29.aspx) and a related *BuilderStrategy* that do clean up.

There is a sample in the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com) (inside TecX.Unity.Lifetime) which is taken from Mark Seemann's book *Dependency Injection in .NET*.